# Existing javascript not executing MVC 5 Telerik

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, telerik-reporting

I have a working MVC 5 application with custom Javascript functions which have been working since I created them.

I now included Telerik as described in the guide here: http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/mvc-report-viewer-extension-embedding.html .

Since I included the Telerik reporting module my Javascript does not work anymore. It is loaded but does not execute. I added an alert in the beginning of the function and the alert is not showing either. As illustration:

```
$('.cbTreeViewItem').click(function () {
    alert("test");
}
```

Is included but not executed. Before adding Telerik it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems adding Telerik slowed down the loading process causing the custom Javascript files not to be properly loaded.

Wrapping my custom Javascript files as below resolved the issue for me.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // custom functions for the given page
})
```